# How to create SHA512 password hashes on command line

Tags: security, password, encryption, hashsum

In Linux I can create a SHA1 password hash using `sha1pass mypassword`. Is there a similar command line tool which lets me create `sha512` hashes? Same question for `Bcrypt` and `PBKDF2`.

Comment: Don't you mean `sha1sum`?

Comment: @Tichodroma no, there is actually a `sha1pass` command, part of the syslinux-common package on Debian.

Comment: There's a `sha512sum` command that's part of coreutils, and similarly `openssl sha512` -- but neither does the extra stuff that `sha1pass` does.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for `mkpasswd`, which (at least on Debian) is part of the `whois` package. Don't ask why...

```
anthony@Zia:~$ mkpasswd -m help
Available methods:
des     standard 56 bit DES-based crypt(3)
md5     MD5
sha-256 SHA-256
sha-512 SHA-512
```

Unfortunately, my version at least doesn't do bcrypt. If your C library does, it should (and the manpage gives a -R option to set the strength). -R also works on sha-512, but I'm not sure if its PBKDF-2 or not.

If you need to generate bcrypt passwords, you can do it fairly simply with the `Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt` Perl module.

Answer (score 98):

On any of the Red Hat distros such as Fedora, CentOS, or RHEL the command `mkpasswd` doesn't include the same set of switches as the version typically included with Debian/Ubuntu.

**NOTE:** The command `mkpasswd` is actually part of the `expect` package, and should probably be avoided. You can find out what package it belongs to with either of these commands.

```
$ yum whatprovides "*/mkpasswd"
-or-
$ repoquery -q --file */mkpasswd
```

#### Example

```
$ repoquery -q --file */mkpasswd
expect-0:5.43.0-8.el5.x86_64
expect-0:5.43.0-8.el5.i386
```

Both of these methods are superior to using `rpm` since the packages do not have to be installed to locate `*/mkpasswd`.

#### Workarounds

To work around this you can use the following Python or Perl one-liners to generate SHA-512 passwords. Take note that these are salted:

#### Python (>= 3.3)

```
$ python -c 'import crypt,getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(), crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

-or scripted-

```
$ python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("somesecret", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

#### Python (2.x or 3.x)

```
$ python -c "import crypt, getpass, pwd; \
             print(crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$saltsalt\$'))"

$6$saltsalt$qFmFH.bQmmtXzyBY0s9v7Oicd2z4XSIecDzlB5KiA2/jctKu9YterLp8wwnSq.qc.eoxqOmSuNp2xS0ktL3nh/
```

Note: $6$ designates sha512.  Support for this method of specifying the algorithm is dependent on support in OS level crypt(3) library function (usually in libcrypt).  It is not dependent on python version.

#### Perl

```
$ perl -e 'print crypt("password","\$6\$saltsalt\$") . "\n"'
$6$saltsalt$qFmFH.bQmmtXzyBY0s9v7Oicd2z4XSIecDzlB5KiA2/jctKu9YterLp8wwnSq.qc.eoxqOmSuNp2xS0ktL3nh/
```

In these examples the password is the string "password" and the salt is "saltsalt". Both examples are using **$6$** which denotes that you want crypt to use SHA-512.

Comment: For the python one-liner, you can use `crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)` to generate the salt instead of using a fixed one.

Comment: @JakeCobb `crypt.mksalt` is only available in Python 3.x

Comment: Before typing a clear-text password at the command line make sure you have "ignorespace" set in HISTCONTROL (i.e., do this first on CentOS/RHEL: echo 'export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups:ignorespace"' > /etc/profile.d/histcontrol.sh && source /etc/profile.d/histcontrol.sh). Otherwise, it'll get saved in your ~/.bash_history.

Comment: the perl (and presumably the python) use the system function "crypt".  So they aren't portable, they require a crypt function that understands the requested hash type.  The OSX crypt doesn't - it just gives me back an old-style DES-encrypted string.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri I have Python 2.7.5 and have access to `crypt.mksalt` on CentOS 7.1

Comment: @user12345 Then it must be something that CentOS has backported from Py 3.x: (1) [the Python docs for 2.7 do not mention `crypt.mksalt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html), (2) on Ubuntu 16.04 I get the following:

    $ python
    Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29)
    [...]
    >>> import crypt
    >>> help(crypt.mksalt)
    [...]
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mksalt'

Comment: @Patrick Much more reliable and more memorable approach: https://www.technovelty.org/linux/skipping-bash-history-for-command-lines-starting-with-space.html . In short, set `HISTCONTROL` to `ignorespace`, the simply precede any command you don't want stored with a space.

Comment: What about `bcrypt` in shell or Perl? The `crypt` approach does not seem to support that.

Comment: Confirmed that crypt on OSX as recent as 10.11 still won't do sha512 under either python or perl.

Comment: the mkpasswd included in expect on Centos does not do sha1 sha256 sha512 bcrypt... I am not sure why its at the top of the answer: https://core.tcl.tk/expect/artifact/8d9337848c793e85

Comment: Same on ArchLinux `pacman -F mkpasswd` it is also delivered by expect bu it's not the same utility at all.

Comment: The Python `crypt.crypt()` method takes a *two character* salt. Note that `crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$saltsalt\$') == crypt.crypt('password', '\$') == '\\$UZoIyj/Hy/c'`... on my machine.

Answer (score 36):

OpenSSL has

```
openssl passwd -6
```

Help says:

```
$ openssl passwd --help
Usage: passwd [options]
Valid options are:
...
 -6                  SHA512-based password algorithm
```

For consistent output you can specify the salt:

```
openssl passwd -6 -salt <YOUR_SALT>
```

Output is something similar to:

```
$6$YOUR_SALT$q/oDR4twC1ik4RoxTJJtX.3MjenHVapkMaBbq2NcRHGQjqhIWRNcEVitYZhyIx98D7lF7qs0vLTq17X0nEr8I.
```

with: `6` between "$" indicating the algorithm ("-6" above), followed by `YOUR_SALT` and "$", finishing with the SHA512 sum.

Comment: (For the record, it looks like this version of openssl is not available in Debian 9)

Comment: This works also in Windows using git-for-windows/cmder/msys2 variants of openssl

Comment: Nice. It always annoyed me to have install the `whois` package for this.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `doveadm` utility, which is included in the `dovecot` package.

```
doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT
```

**Result example:**

```
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0JvQ1LLFESzA16.I$JVdKAIq0igudTq06BMqzT9rL1gRawMPwLr9U3/kBMKUqZdONfa0wubC89C35LKl3aE16CRH57BfGb4ygPLggL1
```

Just cut *{SHA512-CRYPT}* and you'll get your SHA512 hashed string.

Comment: Doesn't work for me as a regular user: `doveadm(jotik): Fatal: Error reading configuration: stat(/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf) failed: Permission denied (euid=1000(jotik) egid=100(users) missing +x perm: /etc/dovecot, we're not in group 97(dovecot), dir owned by 0:97 mode=0750)`

Comment: "Permission denied" is not related to the original question.   The default dovecot setting is not to let end-user read any files in the /etc/dovecot subdirectory, particularily `users` (and `password`) file.  Become root, and then you can see those files.

Comment: The point is that `doveadm` cannot be run by a regular user, so this command is not a solution to the original question for someone who isn't (or cannot become) root. That someone typically isn't interested in reading any files in the /etc/dovecot directory, and shouldn't need to just in order to generate a password hash.

Answer (score 13):

Run this command:

```
$ /sbin/grub-crypt --sha-512
```

then enter the word you want hashed.

Comment: -bash: /sbin/grub-crypt: No such file or directory

Comment: I don't believe grub is on c7 so you can use: 

python -c 'import crypt,getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(),crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @slm's workarounds above, if you're worried about someone getting a hold of your bash history and seeing the plain text password, you can insert `raw_input()` in the python statement where the salt and password fields go so it prompts you for them. The text isn't masked while you're typing, but it won't show up in your bash history. You could also start the command with a leading space, but I always forget to do that.

```
python -c "import crypt, getpass, pwd; print crypt.crypt(raw_input(), '\$6\$' + raw_input() + '\$')"
```

Comment: You can also configure `bash` to not record commands prefixed with a space adding `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` to your `.bashrc` file. When you run a command you want to exclude from your history simply type a space then the actual command.

Comment: You could also use whatever tool you want and use `cat`. For example, `cat | the-tool-expecting-passwd-stdin` can be used and after writing the password to your terminal (now connected to `cat`), simply press Ctrl+D after pressing enter to signal end of input.

Answer (score 1):

## sha512 htpasswd

Command which asks for user and password and generates a regular htpasswd-file:

```
python -c 'import crypt,getpass; print(getpass.getpass("Name: ")+":"+crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(),crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))' >> htpasswd
```

Works with all python versions > 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing with NodeJs before:

```bsh
 echo "console.log(require('crypto').createHmac('sha512', 'nonbase64key').update('password').digest('hex'))" | node
```

it's equivalent in python is:

```bsh
python3 -c 'import hashlib;import base64;import hmac;print(hmac.new(b"nonbase64key", "password".encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest())'
```

And the equivalent shell command is:

```bsh
echo -n "password" | openssl sha512 -hmac "nonbase64key"
```

Answer (score 1):

All examples will be using SHA-512, `<password>` as password placeholder and `<salt>` as salt placeholder.

### mkpasswd

Note: `mkpasswd` binary is installed via the package `whois` on Debian / Ubuntu **only**. On other Linux distribution such as ArchLinux, Fedora, CentOS, openSUSE, etc. `mkpasswd` is provided by the `expect` package but is an totally different utility which is available as `expect_mkpasswd` on Debian / Ubuntu. `whois` of all other Linux distro doesn't include `mkpasswd` but the source (C lang) can be found on the original repository https://github.com/rfc1036/whois.

```bsh
# With a random password and random salt
mkpasswd -m sha-512
# With a random random salt
mkpasswd -m sha-512 '<password>'
# Choosing both password and salt
mkpasswd -m sha-512 '<password>' '<salt>'
# Read password from stdin to avoid leaking it in shell command history
mkpasswd -m sha-512 --stdin
```

### OpenSSL

```bsh
# With a random random salt
openssl passwd -6 '<password>'
# Choosing both password and salt
openssl passwd -6 --salt '<salt>' '<password>'
# Read password from stdin to avoid leaking it in shell command history
openssl passwd -6 -stdin
openssl passwd -6
```

### Ruby

```bsh
# With a random password and random salt
ruby -e 'require "securerandom"; puts SecureRandom.alphanumeric(20).crypt("$6$" + rand(36 ** 8).to_s(36))'
# With a random random salt
ruby -e 'puts "<password>".crypt("$6$" + rand(36 ** 8).to_s(36))'
# Choosing both password and salt
ruby -e 'puts "<password>".crypt("$6$<salt>")'
# Read password from stdin to avoid leaking it in shell command history
ruby -e 'require "io/console"; puts IO::console.getpass.crypt("$6$" + rand(36 ** 8).to_s(36))'
```

Note: for those who complains that `Random#rand` is a PRNG, you can use the secure `SecureRandom#rand` but it's not very important is rand is used only to generate the salt which is publicly available in the hash at the end.

```bsh
ruby -e 'require "securerandom"; puts "<password>".crypt("$6$" + SecureRandom.rand(36 ** 8).to_s(36))'
```

### Perl

```bsh
# Choosing both password and salt
perl -le 'print crypt "<password>", "\$6\$<salt>\$"'
```

### Python

Requires Python >= 3.3

```bsh
# With a random random salt
python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("<password>", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
# Choosing both password and salt
python -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("<password>", "$6$<salt>"))'
# Read password from stdin to avoid leaking it in shell command history
python -c 'import crypt,getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(), crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))
```

### grub-crypt

Note: The `grub` package doesn't include `grub-crypt` in many distros.

```bsh
# With a random random salt
# Read password from stdin to avoid leaking it in shell command history
grub-crypt --sha-512
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using the Python (>= 2.7) method from sim's answer and want to confirm your password before it generates - because you fat finger passwords...

```
$ python -c 'import crypt,getpass;pw=getpass.getpass(); print(crypt.crypt(pw), crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512) if (pw==getpass.getpass("Confirm: ")) else exit())'
```

Comment: In the Nov 29, 2017 version of this answer, it says this works for python 2.7 (or later).  The crypt module of python2.7 does not have mksalt().  Also I think you want the crypt.mksalt() call as the 2nd arg to crypt.crypt() (misplaced close paren?).

Answer (score 0):

openssl version "OpenSSL 1.1.1” on Linux and
openssl version "LibreSSL 2.6.5” on MacOS support md5_crypt.

Just run and enter password:

```
openssl passwd -crypt
Password:
Verifying - Password:
<results_into_a_md5_crypt_password>
```

or provide the plain text password directly to the CLI:

```
openssl password -crypt <plain_text_password_goes_here>
<results_into_a_md5_crypt_password>
```

Comment: `crypt` still might result in **insecure** classic DES implementation, taking only the first eight chars of a password. You can try that with `passwd -crypt -salt oo` multiple times - first using `aaaaaaaa` (8x`a`) and then using `aaaaaaaaaa` (10x`a`) - proofed when both lead to same password hash

Answer (score 0):

## PBKDF2

I wrote a simple application in Go that allows to generate PBKDF2 hash, as OpenSSL does not provide a commandline tool for that.
It supports sha1, sha256, sha512 and md5.

You can build it yourself, or download released binaries in "release" section.

https://github.com/riotkit-org/gpbkdf2

The usage is very simple:

```
gpbkdf2 --passphrase=my-secret-passphrase --salt=my-secret-salt --digest-algorithm=sha512 --digest-rounds=10000 --length=128
```

Comment: Secrets should NEVER written to a command line. Always feed them to your program via a file or an environment variable.

Answer (score -17):

You can use `sha512sum`:

```
echo "password" | sha512sum
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The command will not generate a valid SHA-512 *password* hash. It will simply calculate the checksum of the string password\n (note that there is also a newline in the end). Unix password hashes are salted and include a hash version code between two "$" symbols. See the answer by @slm.

Comment: More specifically, the problem is that while the password is somewhat obfuscated, this method is vulnerable to a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table attack.