# What program in Linux computes the hash of the input password when you log in?

Tags: security, login, authentication

If I understand authentication mechanism correctly, when we input the credentials in the login prompt, the hash of the password is computed and then that hash is compared with the hash stored somewhere, and if I am not mistaken that "somewhere" is the `/etc/shadow`. If it matches, then authentication is successful, otherwise, authentication fails.

My question is, what program, I mean which binary, computes the hash of the input password? Or is it implemented by the kernel?

Answer (score 20):

No *specific* binary does the hashing; it's done by a library call `crypt(3)`.  So, in theory, any program (even a `perl` script) can generate the hash.  e.g.

```
perl -e 'print crypt("hello","\$6\$0abcdef")'
$6$0abcdef$JhsHMeFo8zYQPa8/HDXGoMWZgIxiCJKu2BQqCGjkyh/NadMax6GiJWQOT5ZL7POkUzrwbvL/Yhbx9f8XtLr.F/
```

You can read more about this function by `man 3 crypt`.

Now a normal Unix login process is a bit more complicated.  Typically we use the PAM ("Pluggable Authentication Modules") stack.  This, along with NSS ("Name Service Switch"), allows a lot of flexibility in how and where passwords are stored and how authentication is done.

When using PAM, the program itself doesn't call `crypt()`, it calls the PAM stack and that decides what to use.

A very common pattern is to use `pam_unix` and it will be in `pam_unix.so` that the call to `crypt()` is done, and where the comparison to the `/etc/shadow` (or LDAP or wherever) would be done.

This PAM/NSS combination is very powerful because it means new methods of authentication can be added (e.g. joining Active Directory domains) without every program needing to know about it; just update the PAM configuration and "magic" happens.

Comment: Am I correct if I say that /usr/bin/login, /usr/bin/sudo, /usr/bin/su, /usr/bin/ssh, etc., are examples of applications that may (or may not) use the crypt or PAM?

Comment: @JLC, in practice, all the programs you mention support PAM. (Well -- it's the SSH _daemon_, so `sshd`, that's responsible for PAM support, not the client; but presuming the daemon is what you mean...)

Comment: `sshd` is a special case 'cos it can optionally use PAM or not (the `usePAM` entry in `sshd_config`).  If you do an `ls /etc/pam.d` you'll see lots of entries (eg `su`, `sudo`, `screen`, `passwd`, `login` and more).  These are the PAM configs for those programs.

Comment: So brushing GUI under the carpet for the moment, what have we got: getty calls login and login uses PAM?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd  Yeah.  We can see login uses PAM by seeing that it uses libpam; eg.  `% ldd /bin/login | grep libpam
        libpam.so.0 => /lib64/libpam.so.0 (0x00007f87be58e000)
        libpam_misc.so.0 => /lib64/libpam_misc.so.0 (0x00007f87be38a000)
`

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd See my answer for more details about this part.

Answer (score 8):

> when we input the credentials in the login prompt, the hash of the password is computed and then that hash is compared with the hash stored somewhere, and if I am not mistaken that "somewhere" is the `/etc/shadow`.

This is broadly correct (and more correct than many simplified explanations on the web, so well done). More precisely, the data flow is:

1. Read some configuration files. I'll assume they result in the common case of a local account with the normal defaults. Other possibilities at this stage can result in querying a network account database, or doing non-password-based authentication, or (but this would be unusual) doing password-based authentication with a different location of the password hash.
2. Input the user's password *P*. (This may happen after the next step.)
3. Find the line with the desired user name in [`/etc/shadow`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html) and extract the “encrypted¹ password” field. Note that this step requires permission to read `/etc/shadow`.
4. Split the shadow field into two parts²: the configuration+salt *S* and the expected hash *H*. Pass *P* and *S* to the [`crypt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) library function¹, obtaining a result *R*. Compare *R* with *H*: if they're equal then the password authentication has succeeded, otherwise it's failed.
5. Continue with the user authentication if there are non-password based methods.
6. If the authentication has succeeded, log the user in, otherwise error out.

On a typical embedded Linux system, all these steps happen inside the same program: [`login`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html) for a console login, [`su`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) or [`sudo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sudo.1.html) when elevating privileges, [`dropbear`](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) for SSH logins, etc. Step 1 may be completely omitted since embedded systems often don't have any runtime configurability at this point. The implementation of the `crypt` function comes from the system's standard library, e.g. [musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/crypt). So the code to perform the calculation is stored in something like `/lib/libc.so` while the code that performs the surrounding configuration and database lookups is in `/bin/login` and such. The kernel is not involved in authentication except for providing basic input-output primitives (open file, read file, etc.). The kernel only gets involved more directly after authentication, to keep track of the privileges of the process after the authentication. (It may also be involved for temporary privilege escalation to read `/etc/shadow` if the authentication program doesn't run as root all the time.)

On a typical non-embedded Unix system, most of this process is subcontracted to the [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) library. PAM consists of a main library (`/lib/libpam.so.0` — here and elsewhere the exact path is system-dependent) as well as a number of auxiliary libraries and programs. I won't get into details because they're all part of the same software suite. The authenticating program calls a series of [functions in the PAM library](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam.8.html) to authenticate the user as well as decide what to do after a successful authentication (session establishment). I think [`pam_authenticate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pam_authenticate.3.html) is the function that performs parts of step 1 as well as steps 3–5 (I'm not sure as I'm not familiar with this side of PAM).

With PAM, steps 3–4 (finding the password hash and validating the password against it) are specifically handled in `/lib/security/pam_unix.so`, the [PAM module for traditional password-based authentication](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_unix.8.html). The `pam_unix` module runs in the context of the process that performs the authentication, which might not run with enough privileges to read `/etc/shadow` (but needs to run with enough privileges to be able to get those privileges³). To minimize the amount of code that can access the password hashes, this part runs in a dedicated program [`unix_chkpwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/unix_chkpwd.8.html). This program is the one that reads the password hash from `/etc/shadow`, calls the `crypt` function and verifies its output.

¹  <sub>A misleading name since the password is hashed, not encrypted — you can't “decrypt” the content to find the original password.</sub>

²  <sub>The interface is slightly weird for historical reasons. The field in `/etc/shadow` contains 4 parts: an algorithm identifier, some cost parameters, a salt string, and the expected output string. The algorithm identifier selects which [password hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function#Password_hashing) algorithm is used — note that these are not hashing algorithms despite what the name suggests. See e.g. [Do all Linux distributions use the same cryptographic hash function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/do-all-linux-distributions-use-the-same-cryptographic-hash-function/120684#120684) for more information. The cost parameters depend on the algorithm; a higher cost makes normal authentication slower but also makes cracking the password harder if an attacker manages to retrieve the hash. The salt is unique and protects against multi-account attacks (e.g. trying to get into the account of the employee with the weakest password, to get a foothold into an organization). Internally, the `crypt` function uses the algorithm identifier to determine which auxiliary function to call, and on some systems this auxiliary function can live in a different library.</sub>

³  <sub>Typically, the program (`login`, `su`, …) starts with root privileges, and keeps (at least a part of itself) root as its [saved user ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Saved_user_ID) but changes its [effective user ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Effective_user_ID) to the a dedicated system user (when logging in) or to the invoking user (when elevating privileges). This minimizes the risks of a security hole in the login program that allows an attacker to get partial control of the login program (e.g. read files) but not the ability to execute arbitrary code. Elevating privileges requires calling a dedicated system call such as [`seteuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html).</sub>

Comment: re. point 4, I've had the impression that it's not even really necessary to split the stored password entry to remove the hash proper, as far as I've tried, `crypt()` seems to accept it is-as (and presumably ignores the part it doesn't need). Meaning you can reduce a password check to just comparing the result of `crypt(entered_password, stored_hash)` to the stored hash, and you don't need to even know what the structure of the stored field is. Anyway, the result contains the salt part too, so you can't compare it to just the extracted hash.

Comment: E.g. in Perl, `perl -le '$p = "foobar"; $h = q#$5$rounds=12345$3K4Ah7pu76z$n4i.EB32cHKCBdFfRt4sFiklMu4oflfxKdzr0Do..UB#; $c = crypt($p, $h); print $h; print $c;'` prints out the hash `$5$...UB` twice (since it's the correct password)

Answer (score 3):

The binary responsible for computing the hash of the input password is typically part of the authentication system and is not implemented by the kernel. In most Linux distributions, this is handled by a program called ***crypt*** or ***passwd***, and the specific binary used may vary by distribution.

Here's a simplified overview of how it works:

1. When a user logs in or changes their password, the password is passed
   to the crypt or passwd utility.
2. The crypt or passwd utility computes the hash of the input password
   using a one-way cryptographic hash function. The specific hash
   function used can vary but is commonly based on algorithms like
   SHA-256 or SHA-512.
3. The computed hash is then compared to the stored hash in the
   `/etc/shadow` file for the corresponding user. Note that this means that the utility needs to have permission to read the shadow file.
4. If the two hashes match, the authentication is successful, and the
   user is granted access.

The hashing and password management are typically handled by user-space programs to ensure flexibility and compatibility with various password storage schemes and hashing algorithms. The kernel is only responsible for low-level interactions between the user-space authentication utilities and tracking what user each process runs as.

Comment: This might have been correct 20 years ago, but these days one has to allow for the almost-universal adoption of PAM.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd This is true even when using PAM. The “crypt” program used by PAM is called `unix_chkpwd`.

Comment: That is to say it's not true that the program would be called `crypt`. Ok, it might be true in some system, but I've never heard of a distinct program called `crypt` in any Linux, so if it exists, it's far from universal. The library function `crypt()` would be a different matter, of course.

Comment: Browsing the FreeBSD man pages archive, it looks like [`crypt` in FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypt&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+14.0-STABLE&arch=default&format=html) is a tool for encrypting files, and a similar program has been there in some other systems too.

Comment: I think this answer is not correct as the program is named `login`, not `passwd` or `crypt`.