# /etc/shadow : how to generate $6$ 's encrypted password?

Tags: password, hashsum, shadow

In `/etc/shadow` file there are encrypted password.

Encrypted password is no longer `crypt(3)` or md5 "type 1" format. ([according to this previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow))
Now I have a

```
$6$somesalt$someveryverylongencryptedpasswd
```

as entry.

I can no longer use

```
 openssl passwd -1 -salt salt hello-world
 $1$salt$pJUW3ztI6C1N/anHwD6MB0
```

to generate encrypted passwd.

Any equivalent like (non existing) .. ?

```
 openssl passwd -6 -salt salt hello-world
```

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52108/how-to-create-sha512-password-hashes-on-command-line as well as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow

Comment: You should not be supplying the salt - it should be randomly generated. (The only reason to supply it is to check a password against an existing hash)

Comment: my purpose was precisely to check wether a given string is the actual password, so I have to reuse the salt.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Python:**

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("password", "$6$saltsalt$")'
```

(for python 3 and greater it will be `print(crypt.crypt(..., ...))`)

**Perl:**

```
perl -e 'print crypt("password","\$6\$saltsalt\$") . "\n"'
```

Comment: For Python 2.7 and 3.3: `python -c 'import crypt,getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(), crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'`

Comment: @scyid thank, I dodn't know the $6$salt trick !!

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: `crypt.mksalt()` is not in Python 2.7, only 3.3 onwards.

Comment: Remember that command line arguments are visible to other users via `ps`.  When working with real passwords, don't use these commands as written; instead turn them into a script that reads the password from stdin or a file.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen, python-2.7.5-16.fc20.x86_64 from my Fedora 20 installation has it.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Python 2.7.8 in Ubuntu 14.10 doesn't have it. The [Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html) don't document it. The [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html#crypt.mksalt) say it's new in 3.3.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen, yes, you're right, it seems it has been backported in the [python package for Fedora 20](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/python.git/tree/00165-crypt-module-salt-backport.patch?h=f20).

Answer (score 41):

On Debian-based systems you can use `mkpasswd`.

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 PASSWORD [SALT]
```

(`PASSWORD` is your desired password; [`SALT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) is optional.)

Strangely, that tool is found in the `whois` package.

```
sudo apt-get install whois
```

Comment: +1 for `whois` package name for installation.

Comment: For clarification, `PASSWORD` is your desired password and the `SALT`, explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 can be omitted.

Comment: Is there a command to check if mkpasswd's generated hash is correct? I'm generating it and it constantly fails after I put it in /etc/shadow.

Comment: I'm sure the generated hash would be correct, and your problem would be in something else. But, to verify it, you could generate the hash using an independent implementation of the hash (such as one of the other answers to this question).

Comment: It looks like if SALT is not specified, mkpasswd generates a random one for you. Otherwise, mkpasswd expects the SALT to be between 8 and 16 bytes inclusively.

Comment: You should probably also put a space before this command to prevent your password from being stored in your bash history.