# Simplest way of hashing passwords with multiple different hash algorithms

Tags: command-line, password

I have a large list of plaintext passwords stored in a file `pwds.txt` and would like to obtain the hashed version of these passwords under various different hash algorithms. 
I want one file for each hash algorithm.
As a minimum I would like to obtain hashes under `MD5`, `SHA1`, `SHA256`, (with and without salts) and `bcrypt`.

Is there a simple way of obtaining this, without too much scripting?

I thought about leveraging some of the existing password cracking tools, like `hashcat` or `john`, but unfortunately (to the best of my knowledge) they all start with the assumption that you *already* have a list of hashed passwords and that you now want to crack them.
Basically, I want the opposite! 
I have the plaintext passwords, and want to create the hashed passwords.
I have been unable to come up with a clever combination of command line options (for these two programs) that trick them to output a list of hashes from plaintexts.

**Note**

I have already created a short PHP-script that achieves this for smaller files, but it runs out of memory for the size of password file I need it for.

Comment: Really, this can be achieved with a simple for loop if you have the plain-text passwords in an array. If you don't, `awk` would likely be a more-than-capable tool for the job.

Comment: see [This Question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158400/etc-shadow-how-to-generate-6-s-encrypted-password) for a hint.

Comment: Thanks, but as I noted at the end *I already* know how to do this (algorithmically). However, I need something that is more efficient than php and also contains a large number of hash algorithms. That is why it would have been so nice to use a tool like `hashcat` or `john` since they have optimized implementations of almost any hash algorithm there is.

Comment: Please include your PHP script in the question. And also, consider using a proper language. PHP is an abomination.

Comment: Also, you should post the error message you get when it runs out of memory. Not strictly necessary, but would do no harm. Though I don't understand why that would happen.

Comment: Since this question has been closed (I don't understand why), here are some hints. Call your system's `crypt` function; Python's `crypt` module is handy for that. For bcrypt, which may not be present on your system, look for a bcrypt implementation in your language's standard library or as a third-party library. Note that in addition to the passwords, you'll need to supply salts and itertion counts. Note also that `crypt` with MD5, SHA-1, etc. is not the MD5/SHA-1/… algorithm, but an algorithm that uses the hash function in a loop, mixing in the salt.

Comment: Or more simple than Gilles solution, split the file.

Answer (score 1):

> As a minimum I would like to obtain hashes under MD5, SHA1, SHA256

See:

- `man md5sum`
- `man sha1sum`
- `man sha256sum`

**Beware of the presence of newlines when you use these!**