# Obscuring password in cloud-init userdata startup of AWS EC2 instance

Tags: bash, password, aws, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

An AWS EC2 instance creates a new user during its `cloud-init` startup process, and sets the password for that new user.  Terraform is being used to trigger the creation of the new EC2 instance, which runs Amazon Linux 2.  The password is being sent into the instance via a Terraform variable whose value is interpolated into the bash `USERDATA` script that is run by `cloud-init`.

The problem is that the `cloud-init` log file ( `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` ) is printing out the password value in the persisted logs.

> **What specific syntax needs to be changed in the code below so that the password is NOT persisted in the cloud-init log file?**

The line of code in the bash `cloud-init` `userdata` file that is causing this insecure log entry is currently written as:

```
echo "${var.vm_username}":"${var.vm_pwd}" | chpasswd
```

**NOTE:**  You can ignore the Terraform element if you simply want to consider how to obscure the password from the logs if the command were as follows:

```
echo myusername:mypassword | chpasswd
```

The only reason this OP mentions Terraform is to point out that the password is not being persisted in the `cloud-init` `userdata` script.

Comment: provide `chapsswd` with an encrypted password (**-e, --encrypted**), some ways to do are mentioned in answer to my question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158400/etc-shadow-how-to-generate-6-s-encrypted-password (as you are generating EC2 instances from script, using python/shell to encrypt a string should be a trivial matter to you).

Comment: It's not just the log, you will also find in clear text under `/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts`. Store the password encrypted in AWS secrets manager or EC2 parameter store and then fetch it using awscli from the userdata script