# Using bash variables in perl command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl, quoting

I am trying to generate a hashed password as in `/etc/shadow` file, using bash script. The user is prompted for the password which is saved in a variable `PSWD`. I have extracted the Hash and the salt value from the `/etc/shadow` file and saved them in a variables `HVAL` and `SVAL` respectively.

Now in order to generate a hashed password using Password and the Salt value, I need to use command given below ([Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76337/48188)):

`$ perl -e 'print crypt("password","\$6\$salt\$") . "\n"'`

In the above command, I must replace "password" with the `$PSWD` variable, "6" with `$HVAL` and "salt" with `$SVAL` variable.

I've tried exporting above variables and replacing them in the perl command, as shown below, but it was totally messed up.

`perl -e 'print crypt("$ENV{"PSWD"}","\$$ENV{"HVAL"}\$$ENV{"SVAL"}\$") . "\n"'`

What will be the corrections?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas- I've used the backticks while assigning the output to a variable, still it is not working.

Comment: Yes, there's also the problem of the quotes, you'd need `"$ENV{\"VAR\"}"` though `"$ENV{VAR}"` would be enough, see my answer.

Comment: If the password is being changed: The hash should be re-generated. If only testing the password then ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with your double quotes. Here you don't need to quote those hash keys as they are *simple identifiers*. From `perldoc perldata`:

> In fact, a simple identifier within such curlies is forced to be a string, and likewise within a hash subscript. Neither need quoting.  Our earlier example, `$days{'Feb'}` can be written as `$days{Feb}` and the quotes will be assumed automatically.  But anything more complicated in the subscript will be interpreted as an expression.  This means for example that `$version{2.0}++` is equivalent to `$version{2}++`, not to `$version{'2.0'}++`.

So:

```
perl -le 'print crypt($ENV{PSWD},"\$$ENV{HVAL}\$$ENV{SVAL}\$")'
```

If you're using it inside backticks, you'd need to double your backslashes as in:

```
var=`perl -le 'print crypt($ENV{PSWD},"\\$$ENV{HVAL}\\$$ENV{SVAL}\$")'`
```

Best is to use the `$(...)` form of command substitution instead:

```
var=$(perl -le 'print crypt($ENV{PSWD},"\$$ENV{HVAL}\$$ENV{SVAL}\$")')
```

Comment: A comment that the vars are passed in the environment to avoid being seen in `ps -ef` will help understand the command concept.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence to get to the correct quote starts with the original command:

```
perl -e 'print crypt("password","\$6\$salt\$") . "\n"'
```

Let's add some space:

```
perl -e 'print crypt("  password  ","\$  6  \$  salt  \$") . "\n"'
```

Let's change the vars to their equivalents:

```
perl -e 'print crypt("  $ENV{PSWD}  ","\$  $ENV{HVAL}  \$  $ENV{SVAL}  \$") . "\n"'
```

The equivalents should not be quoted, as in quotes they fail:

```
perl -e 'print "$ENV{PSWD}" . "\n"'      # correct.
perl -e 'print "$ENV{"PSWD"}" . "\n"'    # fail.
```

And finally, lets remove the spaces inserted above:

```
perl -e 'print crypt("$ENV{PSWD}","\$$ENV{HVAL}\$$ENV{SVAL}\$") . "\n"'
```

then, the command may be assigned to a variable.

```
var="$(  perl -e 'print crypt("$ENV{PSWD}","\$$ENV{HVAL}\$$ENV{SVAL}\$") . "\n"'  )"
```

With exported values: `PSWD=password`, `HVAL=6`, `SVAL=saltsalt` I get:

$6$saltsalt$qFmFH.bQmmtXzyBY0s9v7Oicd2z4XSIecDzlB5KiA2/jctKu9YterLp8wwnSq.qc.eoxqOmSuNp2xS0ktL3nh/