# Add user and set password using Ansible

Tags: users, useradd, ansible

I have created an Ansible playbook to create user and set password. But it is giving me an error

> ERROR: password is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: root
  vars:
  password: jbJe1oRlSZKQ6
  tasks:
    - user: name=testuser password={{password}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: you need to indent `password:` in your playbook, because you want it to be a variable:

```
vars:
  password: hashed_password
```

If it's not indented then Ansible considers it a play parameter and throws an error because `password` is not.

---

Second: unless you are setting the password for a user on OSX, you need to provide a hashed value of a password. Follow the detailed [instructions](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module), but basically you need to provide the output of:

```
mkpasswd --method=SHA-512
```

Or install `passlib` with:

```
pip install passlib
```

and run:

```
python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; import getpass; print sha512_crypt.encrypt(getpass.getpass())"
```

Comment: related when using mkpasswd: [How to create SHA512 password hashes on command line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52108/how-to-create-sha512-password-hashes-on-command-line/76337#76337)

Comment: I am using centos 7 and i have create password using "python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("This is my Password", "test123")'". For centos unable to get packages for mkpasswd.

Comment: thanks. now i am able to create user but when i am login with newly created user it is not accepting the passwd which i have set using ansible.

Comment: @user163575 And what are you going to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
- hosts: Your_host_name
   become: True
   vars:
     # created with:
     # python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("This is my Password", "$1$SomeSalt$")'
     password: $1$SomeSalt$aIJ0bvHJBSYd307VQuuD90

   tasks:
     - user: name=tset password={{password}} state=present
```