# "Wrong salt length" message at login. What algorithm to use to generate user password?

Tags: password, encryption

I'm trying to change programmatically a user's password, and got a few messages I can't explain along the way.

I ran this command to start with:

```
sudo usermod -p "$(openssl passwd -1 newpassword)" theuser
```

No error got printed, but next time I logged in, I got this message:

> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
>   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
>   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
>
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
>   permitted by applicable law.
>   Last login: Mon Jan 30 16:22:41 2017 from 193.50.110.1
>   Wrong salt length: 0 bytes when 8 <= n <= 16 expected.

I tried another encryption method:

```
sudo usermod -p "$(openssl passwd -crypt newpassword)" theuser
```

Still no error, but the message changed:

> Wrong salt length: 0 bytes when 8 <= n <= 16 expected.

I finally tried something else, using `mkpasswd` to have a stronger encryption (related to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52108/how-to-create-sha512-password-hashes-on-command-line)):

```
sudo usermod -p "$(mkpasswd --method=sha-512 newpassword)" theuser
```

This time, the error disappeared, so I believe this was related to the hash algorithm strength. What I don't understand is which algorithm can and should be used to generate a password.

Which algorithms can be safely used with `mkpasswd` to avoid the message error? Does that also mean `mkpasswd` command is ran at startup?

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention I had these messages using a Raspbian Jessie Lite. I also found some strings containing this error message in mkpasswd.c source on [rfc1036/whois](https://github.com/rfc1036/whois/blob/next/mkpasswd.c#L259-L263) GitHub repository.

Comment: You should use `--method=sha-512`, because `-1` and `-crypt` select obsolete, weak methods. But that doesn't explain the error message. `-1` and `-crypt` are insecure but they should work, functionally speaking.

Comment: Hi @Gilles, thanks for the information, this could be an accepted answer if that was one hehe. I wasn't expecting weak encryption to be present in that part of the code, but may be it is kept for compatibility purpose. That being said, It raises another question which is why the message popping here, and what is the inner mechanism that triggers it.

Comment: Do not expect `openssl` to protect you against using insecure algorithms. Its interface is badly designed and it's difficult to use securely even if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Is there any way to now what is the lowest encryption that would be safe to use?

Comment: The only portable, secure methods are `sha-256` and `sha-512`. You know that, um, unfortunately not because the documentation tells you, you have to figure it out by asking around (and figuring out who can give you reliable answers...).